# Node server restart causing multiple issues: ng-click, ng-model for one element only not recognised

Tags: node.js, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-model

The application was working fine until I restarted the node server. I tried pulling my last commit from git (which worked fine) and running it, but the same error.

'npm start' gives an error : could not find module '../app', but i can load the page on the localhost after running the command : node server.js.

There are multiple ng-models on the page. All are recognized in the controller except tabVm.answer. Also, ng-click is not fired either.

template:

```
<div class="container box col-lg-6">
       <div class="inBox">
           <form role="form" name="contactForm">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" ng-model="tabVm.name" class="form-control" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Email</label>
                   <input type="email" ng-model="tabVm.email" class="form-control" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Contact Number</label>
                   <input type="tel" ng-model="tabVm.number" class="form-control">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Message</label>
                   <input type="text" ng-model="tabVm.message" class="form-control textBox" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="spamTag">No-Spam</label>
                   <input type="number" ng-model="tabVm.answer" class="form-control" required>
               </div>
           </form>
           <button type="submit" class="btn large-btn" ng-click="sendMsg()" >Send</button>

       </div>
   </div>
```

controller:

```
  angular.module('MySite').controller('TabCtrl',TabCtrlFn);
    TabCtrlFn.$inject=['$scope','$location','$window','sendMessage'];
    function TabCtrlFn($scope,$location,$window,sendMessage){
        $scope.linkedIn=function(){
            $window.location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/dpm';
        }
        $scope.facebook=function(){
            $window.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dpm';
        }
        var tabVm=this;



    /* Viewer Message submit routine
    *  Service : messageService.js
    *  Function: sendMsg(config);
    */
    $scope.sendMsg=function(){
        if((tabVm.num1 + tabVm.num2)==tabVm.answer){
            //Create JSON object
            var data={
                params:{
                    'name': tabVm.name,
                    'email':tabVm.email,
                    'number':tabVm.number,
                    'messgae':tabVm.message
                },
            }

            sendMessage.sendMsg(data);
        }

    }


}
```

The messageService is defined in another script.

Please help. Thank you.

All the above issues started only after I restarted the node server. How can I trouble-shoot so I do not go around in circles, debugging the same issues repeatedly ?

EDIT:

```
|   contributors.txt
|   npm-debug.log
|   output.txt
|   package.json
|   server.js
|   
+---.idea
|           
+---bin
|       
+---node_modules
|                   
+---public
|   |   index.html
|   |   
|   +---images
|   |       
|   +---Scripts
|   |   |   app.js
|   |   |   
|   |   +---ABC
|   |   |      abc.js
|   |   |       
|   |   +---Contact Form
|   |   |       messageService.js
|   |   |       
|   |   +---PQR
|   |   |       pqr.js
|   |   |       pqrService.js
|   |   |       
|   |   \---Tab Navigation
|   |           
|   |           
|   +---stylesheets
|   |       MyStyle.css
|   |       
|   \---Templates
|           Lot of templates here    
+---routes
|       index.js
|       users.js
|       
\---views
        error.jade
        index.jade
        layout.jade
```

Comment: What's the command tied to `npm start`? What's your folder structure look like?

Comment: @Quy : I uploaded the directory structure. From my understanding, 'npm start' should start the application, which comes down to node server.js if no specific start-up script is present. I run both npm start and node server.js from the root node in the above folder structure.

Comment: The application runs just fine now, without having changed anything !! I restarted the node plenty times. Can someone tell me what was wrong in case this happens again ?